# Listing top three names which have the most blank values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two classes (ABC and XYZ) and some students which have taken test in these classes. However, due to personal reason, a few students couldn't take several of the exams. I want to find the top 3 amounts of test not taken and top 3 names of the students that haven't taken the most exams. Below is an illustration of what I'm trying to do:

[image: Test Scores]

In cell F3, I've written the following code to get the top 3 amount of test not taken:

```
=LARGE(COUNTIFS(C:C,"="&"",B:B,UNIQUE(FILTER(OFFSET($B$2,0,0,COUNTA(B:B)-1,1),OFFSET($A$2,0,0,COUNTA(A:A)-1,1)=$F$2))),ROWS(B$2:B2))
```

My goal is to now list the top 3 non test taker names. I've tried a variation of the above code but can't seem to make it work. I have excel version 2209 if this helps. Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Please help use next time to put the input data in table markdown format. You can use the following tool: [Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=LET(x,UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B,(A:A=F1)*(C:C=""))),SORTBY(x,MAP(x,LAMBDA(y,COUNTIFS(A:A,F1,B:B,y,C:C,""))),-1))
```

---

Or, for both names and count:

[image]

```
=LET(x,UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B,(A:A=F1)*(C:C=""))),SORT(HSTACK(x,MAP(x,LAMBDA(y,COUNTIFS(A:A,F1,B:B,y,C:C,"")))),2,-1))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I know I'm asking for a bit too much, but is there a way to only show the top three for both names and count?

Comment: @OscarV, to get the top three, nest the above formula in `=TOCOL(TAKE(<Formula>,3),,1)` to stack names above count.

Comment: Apologies I wasn't clearer. I liked the way you showed the names and numbers right next to each other, but I just need to show the top three names based on the amount of blanks. Basically, only the top three results of your above formula. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: @OscarV, right, then njust nest the formula in `=TAKE(.....,3)`, sorry I forgot to include that in my answer

Comment: THIS IS A HUGE HELP! Thank you so much again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following in `E2` cell:

```
=TAKE(SORT(HSTACK(UNIQUE(B2:B14),
 COUNTIFS(B2:B14, UNIQUE(B2:B14), C2:C14, "")),2,-1),3,1)
```

or using `LET` to avoid repetition and define the inputs first:

```
=LET(x, B2:B14,y, C2:C14,
 TAKE(SORT(HSTACK(UNIQUE(x),COUNTIFS(x, UNIQUE(x),y,"")),2,-1),3,1))
```

Here is the output:
[image: excel output]

`COUNTIFS` counts the total number of blanks for unique names, the rest is just to accommodate the result to the output needs, i.e. sorting via `SORT`, pick the first three rows and only select names via `TAKE`.

If you need the result for a specific class, you can add an additional condition to `COUNTIFS` as follow or using a reference. For example for `ABC` class:

```
=TAKE(SORT(HSTACK(UNIQUE(B2:B14),
 COUNTIFS(B2:B14, UNIQUE(B2:B14),A1:A14, "ABC", C2:C14,"")),2),3,1)
```